# What is the corresponding freebsd command of these rpm commands?

Tags: freebsd, package-management, rpm

I learnt about how to create package and know I want learn how to get some information about packages or files. Can somebody give me corresponding freebsd commands of below rpm commands?

```
rpm -qlp <package> # list files of a package
rpm -qf <file>     # show package name that file belong to
rpm -aq            # show all installed packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking nano as an example,

to list package contents, use

`pkg_info -L nano-2.2.6`

to query owner of a file,

`pkg_info -W /usr/local/bin/nano`

The last one is easy, just run

`pkg_info`

Comment: Just remember that the systems are different, some things just won't have a translation. Learn how to use the FreeBSD system natively (just like they tell you when learning a foreign language: don't translate, think in it).